# Duplicate GA cookies on each refresh

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics on my site.

On each page visit or refresh, cookies of the following structure gets duplicated

```
_gd1484468852473 (_gd + timestamp)
```

This keeps happening until I have 100s of the same cookie and server requests fail

I use the following autotrack extensions

```
  ga('require', 'cleanUrlTracker');
  ga('require', 'outboundLinkTracker');
  ga('require', 'outboundFormTracker');
  ga('require', 'pageVisibilityTracker');
  ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker');
```

Any ideas to why?